# Perl, grouping Array of Array element based on one column and condition

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I have an AoA construct with four columns and many rows. Following is an example of data (input).

```
DQ556929    103480190   103480214   154943
DQ540839    103325247   103325275   2484
DQ566549    103322763   103322792   99
DQ699634    103322664   103322694   0
DQ544472    103322664   103322692   373
DQ709105    103322291   103322318   46
DQ705937    103322245   103322273   486
DQ699398    103321759   103321788   1211
DQ710151    103320548   103320577   692251
DQ548430    102628297   102628326   1
DQ558403    102628296   102628321   855795
DQ692476    101772501   101772529   481463
DQ544274    101291038   101291068   484047
DQ723982    100806991   100807020   1
DQ709023    100806990   100807020   3
DQ712307    100806987   100807014   0
DQ709654    100806987   100807012   571051
DQ707370    100235936   100235962   1481849
```

I want to group and write into a file all the row elements (sequentially).
Conditions are if column four values less than 1000 and minimum two values are next to each other, group them else if the value less than 1000 and lies between the values more than 1000 treat them as single and append separately in the same file and the values which are more than 1000 also write as a block but with out affecting the order of the 2nd and third column.

This file is output of my previous program, now for this I have tried implementing my hands but getting some weird results. Here is my chunk of code, but non functional. Guys I need just help if i am executing my logic well here, I am open for any comments as a beginner. And also correct me anywhere.

```
my @dataf= sort{ $a->[1]<=> $b->[1]} @data;
@dataf=reverse @dataf;
for(my $i>=0;$i<=$#Start;$i++)
{
    print "$sortStart[$i]\n";
    my $diff = $sortStart[$i] - $sortStart[$i+1];
    $dataf[$i][3]= $diff;
#   $IDdiff{$ID[$i]}=$diff;
}

#print Dumper(@dataf);

open (CLUST, ">> ./clustTest.txt" );
for (my $k=0;$k<=$#Start;$k++)
{   

    for (my $l=0;$l<=3;$l++)
    {
#       my $tempdataf = shift $dataf[$k][$l];
#       print $tempdataf;       

        if ($dataf[$k][3]<=1000)
        {
            $flag = 1;
            do
            {
                print CLUST"----- Cluster $clustNo -----\n";
                print CLUST"$dataf[$k][$l]\t";
                if ($dataf[$k][3]<=1000)
                {
                    $flag1 = 1;
                }else {$flag1=0;}

            $clustNo++;
            }until($flag1==0 && $data[$k][3] > 1000);

            if($flag1==0 && $data[$k][3] > 1000)
            {
                print CLUST"Singlet \n";
                print CLUST"$dataf[$k][$l]\t";
                next;
            }
        #print CLUST"$dataf[$k][$l]\t";     #@IDdiff

        }

    print CLUST"\n";
    }
}
```

Expected output in file:

> Singlets
>   `DQ556929   103480190   103480214   154943
>   DQ540839    103325247   103325275   2484`
>
> Cluster1
>   `DQ566549   103322763   103322792   99
>   DQ699634    103322664   103322694   0
>   DQ544472    103322664   103322692   373
>   DQ709105    103322291   103322318   46
>   DQ705937    103322245   103322273   486`
>
> Singlets
>   `DQ699398   103321759   103321788   1211
>   DQ710151    103320548   103320577   692251
>   DQ548430    102628297   102628326   1
>   DQ558403    102628296   102628321   855795
>   DQ692476    101772501   101772529   481463
>   DQ544274    101291038   101291068   484047`
>
> Cluster2
>   `DQ723982   100806991   100807020   1
>   DQ709023    100806990   100807020   3
>   DQ712307    100806987   100807014   0`
>
> Singlets
>   `DQ709654   100806987   100807012   571051
>   DQ707370    100235936   100235962   1481849`

Comment: Could you add the expected output for the given input sample? The description of the logic is fuzzy.

Comment: Don't use bareword filehandles, don't use 2-arg open, don't ignore `open` errors.

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`. I'm pretty sure that would have found `my $i>=0;`, for example.

Comment: @melpomene, yes I got a warning at $i>=0, but don't know why it is giving that. its numerical equating isn't it?

Comment: @Kanhu `my $i >= 0` defines a new variable `$i` containing `undef`. Then it compares `undef` to `0` (numerically). Then it throws the result of the comparison away. It's otherwise equivalent to `my $i` (also, why would you want to compare a variable you only just created?). What you probably meant to write is `my $i = 0;`.

Comment: @melpomene, but perl allows inline declaration of variable, isn't it?

Comment: @Kanhu What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @melpomene, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to produce the expected output. I'm not sure I understood the specification correctly, so there might be errors and edge cases.

How it works: it remembers what kind of section it's currently outputting ($section, `Singlet` or `Cluster`). It accumulates lines in the @cluster array if they belong together, when an incompatible line arrives, the cluster is printed and a new one is started. If the cluster to print has only one member, it's treated as a singlet.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $section = q();
my @cluster;
my $cluster_count = 1;

sub output {
    if (@cluster > 1) {
        print "Cluster$cluster_count\n";
        $cluster_count++;

    } elsif (1 == @cluster) {
        print $section = 'Singlet', "s\n" unless 'Singlet' eq $section;
    }

    print for @cluster;
    @cluster = ();
}

my $last = 'INF';
while (<>) {
    my ($id, $from, $to, $value) = split;
    if ($value > 1000 || 1000 < abs($last - $from)) {
        output();

    } else {
        $section = 'Cluster';
    }

    push @cluster, $_;
    $last = $to;
}
output();
```